# Measure request processing time with Azure Function App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to measure the time taken to process each request in Azure Function App, like below via ASP.NET (non ASP.NET CORE)

```
public class RequestLogHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public RequestLogHandler(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            string path = request.GetOwinContext().Request.Path.ToString();
            string method = request.Method.Method;

            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            sw.Stop();

            int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

            _logger.HttpRequest(path, method, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString(), statusCode.ToString());

            return response;
        }
    }
```

**Setup**

```
 public class WebServer : IWebServer
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly HttpConfiguration _httpConfiguration;

        private IDisposable _server;

        public WebServer(ILogger logger, HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpConfiguration = httpConfiguration;
        }

        public void Start(string url)
        {
            _server = WebApp.Start(url, (appBuilder) =>
            {
                _httpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
                _httpConfiguration.MessageHandlers.Add(new RequestLogHandler(_logger));

                appBuilder.UseWebApi(_httpConfiguration);
            });
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if(_server != null)
            {
                _server.Dispose();
                _server = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring) to get the Request Duration, in the application insights page you could get the request duration details.

[image]

This is the [Duration description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-request-telemetry#duration): This field is required as request telemetry represents the operation with the beginning and the end. You also could use the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights NuGet package to [send custom telemetry data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#log-custom-telemetry-in-c-functions) to Application Insights including the Duration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this is not exactly what I requested. I can see it from App Insights, which is good. But I was looking for coding, which measures the time for whole request in request pipeline. This logic can measure ALL requests. Telemetry, I have to code it for each fucntion, and it doesn't measure the whole request.